# HTML form POST $_REQUEST data disappearing

Tags: php, html, forms

I have checked over this code a few times.

Here's the form to send the POST data:

```
<form action="/loginwizard" method="post">
<input type="hidden" name="action" value="login">
Email:
<br>
<input type="text" name="email" id="email" size=100>
<br>
Password:
<br>
<input type="password" name="pword" id="pword" size=100>
<br>
<input type="submit" value="Login">
</form>
```

My php script uses:

```
print_r($_REQUEST);
```

And the result of this is:

```
Array()
```

This is using:

PHP: version 5.6.8,

System: Windows NT XXX-PC 6.1 build 7601 (Windows 7 Home Premium Edition Service Pack 1) i586

Apache: Apache/2.4.12 (Win32) OpenSSL/1.0.1l PHP/5.6.8

and if it counts for anything, always_populate_raw_post_data set to 0

Comment: Please show your post from startpage until `print_r($_REQUEST)`. Your form works correctly.

Comment: @fusion3k - does the form work correctly? That's a suspicious looking action - unless the OP has custom URLs going on, that may not actually work.

Comment: @cale_b Of course I am referring to the syntax, man.

Comment: The ODDEST thing about this is if I CHANGE action="/loginwizard" to action="/loginwizard/index.php" The form works great. I have a suspicion this is due to something in the Xampp installation? I used to write code all the time passing data this way.

Answer (score 2):

> The ODDEST thing about this is if I CHANGE action="/loginwizard" to action="/loginwizard/index.php" The form works great. I have a suspicion this is due to something in the Xampp installation?

It's because of the [`DirectorySlash`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_dir.html#directoryslash) directive, which is set to `On` by default.

It causes Apache to issue an external redirect to the URL with a trailing slash - and that redirect is followed by the browser using a GET request, and therefor your POST data is lost.

Turning that directive off might have security implications, see the warning in the manual - but it should not be necessary, just point your form action to the directory with trailing slash in the first place:

```
<form action="/loginwizard/" method="post">
                          ^
```

Then the request will be passed to the index file/script for that directory (via the `DirectoryIndex` directive), which is the `index.php` in this case, but without an external redirect, so that your POST data will be present  - in either `$_REQUEST` or `$_POST`. If you only want this script to work with the data if it is received via a POST request, then I suggest to use the latter, to be more specific. Otherwise, GET and COOKIE data might interfere, depending on PHP's `request_order`/`variables_order` configuration setting values.

Answer (score 0):

According to your [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35374898/html-form-post-request-data-disappearing#comment58468638_35374898). `/loginwizard` is your folder name. Apache (possible with default XAMPP installation) recognizes a call to folder, e.g `http://localhost/loginwizard` on a browser as a call to it's [DirectoryIndex](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_dir.html#directoryindex) script. In your case, **index.php** file. So, it's equal to `http://localhost/loginwizar/index.php`

In PHP, this is different case. You should really looking on the script file (and the correct path to it) while requesting on it. Such as, in your case, a form submission.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with @Chyan22 here

/loginwizard  can be either 
1) folder name (in plain php)
2) controller name (in MVC model)
which is not clearly mentioned in the question.

In both cases, the form action should point to the actual destination.

hence, if case of 
1) please include the full path to the file name
2) if not already exists controller named, loginwizard create it. Then load the corresponding view.